# DNS Record change causing bounces

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf, dkim

I have three domains linked to my server (the server's IP Address is xx.xx.xxx.xx)

I have had no issues with bounces or delays over the last year.
Then I made the following changes:

**domainA.com**

OLD (NO DKIM RECORD, BUT PREVIOUS SPF IS):

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook -all"
```

NEW, Changed SPF record to include code for sending through Mandrill:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook include:spf.mandrillapp.com -all"
```

Added DKIM record for Mandrill

```
"v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=blahblahblah\;"
```

**domainB.com**

OLD: NO PREVIOUS SPF OR DKIM RECORD

Added SPF record to include code for sending through Mandrill:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all"
```

Added DKIM record for Mandrill

```
"v=DKIM1\; k=rsa\; p=blahblahblah\;"
```

**domainC.net**

No changes but the SPF record for the last year for this domain has been

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ipv4:xx.xx.xxx.xx -all"
```

We've always sent emails from domainC.net from our server and have not had issues. Then when I made changes to domainA.com and domainB.com, somehow it seems domainC.net was affected.

Then after checking up on things, I noticed an error on domainC.net.

It should be:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ip4:xx.xx.xxx.xx -all"
```

not

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com ipv4:xx.xx.xxx.xx -all"
```

(notice *ip4* vs *ipv4*). Though this is not correct, we did not get any bounces with *ipv4* in the record. I made the change from *ipv4* to *ip4*.

But even with that change we were still bouncing or getting delays. This is only happening to a select number of recipients and a number of people  are receiving. Also with ***ipv4*** in the record we did not get any bounces (quite odd).

For troubleshooting, I changed everything back to what they were before I made the mandrill changes and I still see bounces and delays. I'm not sure what is up. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending all mail via `protection.outlook.com`, it likely doesn't matter if you have `ipv4` vs `ip4`. SPF would validate using the `spf.protection.outlook.com` include.

DNS is cached.  This will cause delays in change propagation. Check your TTL values to see how long you can expect old data to stick around.  When making changes set a short TTL (30 minutes to an hour), until you are sure you have the correct values.

Sites are getting increasing strict on which hosts they will accept mail from.  Any configuration errors may cause issues.

Configuring a `DMARC` record with reporting enable should get you delivery reports from at least Gmail, Yahoo and Micosoft.

If you can get the headers from a delayed message, there may hints as to where the message is getting delayed.  Check the received headers for arrival times.  Check the for validation headers to see if it has any hints.

Answer (score 0):

Having a mis-configured SPF can cause issues at different providers, according to standards, SPF Validators are suppose to syntax check the SPF Record first and reject it as a PERMERROR.

```
4.6.  Record Evaluation

   The check_host() function parses and interprets the SPF record to
   find a result for the current test.  The syntax of the record is
   validated first, and if there are any syntax errors anywhere in the
   record, check_host() returns immediately with the result "permerror",
   without further interpretation or evaluation.
```

But I seen some validators ignore the standard, take the good faith approach and some implement the standard as it's defined.

The best thing you can do is just send an email to "mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com" from each of the domains and see what it picks up. It might be something silly and totally un-related to the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could **change the -all (tells server to reject) to ~ALL (warns)** while you trouble shoot this. You definitely want to use ip4: as that's correct.

Though warns is not as strong as rejects it'll give you some breathing room while figuring this out. I'd recommend checking out your SPF records using a troubleshooting tool like [SPF Surveyer](https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/). Does this return anything useful?